# Convert a complex string to a list in python

Tags: python, string

I retrieved the sting below form mysql table using python and I am having difficulty converting it into a list.

```
_string='[1,2,3,4]'
```

My attempt

```
>>> _string='[1,2,3,4]'
>>> sum(list(_string),[])
>>> list(_string)
['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ']']

>>> _string.strip('\n')
'[1,2,3,4]'
```

Desired output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Is there and efficient way to get the desired output? as I will be doing a millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing a bit - if your string is always a JSON formatted list, you could go with:

```
data = json.loads('[1, 2, 3, 4]')
```

Comment: your solution is just what I wanted. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

Its what that [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is for,you can simply use it to safely evaluating strings containing Python values :

```
>>> _string='[1,2,3,4]'
>>> 
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(_string)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
your_list = _string.strip("[]").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using List comprehension and split

```
In [14]: [int(i) for i in _string[1:-1].split(',')]
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```